# Change color of zoom rectangle

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

I'm using OxyPlot in my application. I want to change the color of the rectangle  when marking an area for zooming.

I just used Controller to bind the left mouse button to zoom:

```
ChartController = new PlotController(); 
ChartController.BindMouseDown(OxyMouseButton.Left,PlotCommands.ZoomRectangle);
```

Comment: could you please share your attempted code ?

Comment: I just used Controller to bind the left mouse button to zoom: ChartController = new PlotController(); ChartController.BindMouseDown(    OxyMouseButton.Left,PlotCommands.ZoomRectangle);

Comment: @Smadar Tsdaka: When adding code, please edit the question. Don't add it in a comment. That way it is more useful for others with the same problem. I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Color the Zoom Rectangle in Oxyplot, you can customize the ZoomRectangleTemplate.

For Example,

```
<oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding MyModel}" Controller="{Binding ChartController,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <oxy:PlotView.ZoomRectangleTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Rectangle Fill="Orange" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </oxy:PlotView.ZoomRectangleTemplate>
</oxy:PlotView>
```

This would provide you the desired output

[image]

Comment: @SmadarTsdaka Glad to help you, kindly mark it as answer it helped in resolving your issue, so that it would be helpful for others.